# Trying to set textview

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my class it goes in to infinite loop please check where I am going wrong ... I am trying to get id's of image view making it random and then trying to set text view with imageview's description

```
public class Object {

int ObectIds[];
LinearLayout HUDDisplay;
int HudDisplayText[] = {R.id.HUD_Text_Element1,
        R.id.HUD_Text_Element2,
        R.id.HUD_Text_Element3,
        R.id.HUD_Text_Element4,
        R.id.HUD_Text_Element5,
        R.id.HUD_Text_Element6,
        R.id.HUD_Text_Element7};

TextView[] text;
View v;

Object(Context context,View vs) {
    super();
    ObectIds = new int[8];
    HUDDisplay=(LinearLayout)vs.findViewById(R.id.HUD_Display);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        ObectIds[i] = (R.id.imageView1) + i;
        Log.d("ImageView", "Image Id's " + ObectIds[i]);

    }

    randomize(vs);
    setTextView();

}

public void setTextView()
{
    for(int i=0;i<8;++i)
    {
         text[i] =(TextView) HUDDisplay.findViewById(HudDisplayText[i]);

         text[i].setText(v.getContentDescription());
    }
}

public void randomize(View vs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        while (true) {
            shuffleArray(ObectIds);
         v = vs.findViewById(ObectIds[i]);
            Log.d("Image", "Image Id's " + v.getId());
            if (!v.isClickable()) {
                v.setClickable(true);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

static void shuffleArray(int[] ar) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        // Simple swap
        int a = ar[index];
        ar[index] = ar[i];
        ar[i] = a;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a while(true) loop that you break from only if v is not clickable. What happens if v is clickable? Nothing in your code ever sets v to not clickable, and views by default are not clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Hey man I observed your code & found error in code :

Please compare following code with your code... Constructor

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        ObectIds[i] = **HudDisplayText[i]**;
        Log.d("ImageView", "Image Id's " + ObectIds[i]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're using the Object class. Object is basically the root of which all classes extend. If you call super() in the constructor, it will call the super class constructor, which is Object as well... That might be the problem.

Try looking for tutorials on how to start with Java/Android, since you are also using variables names that are not recommended. E.g. in Java,:
- a Class starts with a Capital
- a variable, starts with lowercase
- a function starts with lowercase:

```
public class Captial
{
    private int anIntegerStartsWithLowerCase;

    private void functionsAreLowerCaseAsWell()
    {
    }
}
```

Also take a look at your loop... It looks like it is never ending